# How to suppress the 'Handle Unavailable Layers' window when reading a QGIS project

Tags: pyqgis

In PyQGIS, I'm using QgsProject.instance().read(project_file) to open a QGIS project, but when the project contains unavailable layers, the window 'Handle Unavailable Layers' always appears.
How to suppress this window with PyQGIS?

Answer (score 0):

The API provides a way to set a custom bad layer handler which you could use to suppress the 'Handle Unavailable Layers' dialog.

```
class BadLayerDoNothingHandler(QgsProjectBadLayerHandler):
        def handleBadLayers(self, dom_nodes):
            # skip any bad layer handling by doing nothing
            pass
            
QgsProject.instance().setBadLayerHandler(BadLayerDoNothingHandler())
QgsProject.instance().read(project_file)
```

Comment: Not sure though on how you would reset it to the standard bad layer handler if thats required. Something like `QgsProject().instance().setBadLayerHandler(QgsProjectBadLayerHandler())` does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Good idea. This code works:

```
class CustomBadLayerHandler(QgsProjectBadLayerHandler):
    def handleBadLayers(self, layerStrings):
        pass

# Set the custom bad layer handler
bad_layer_handler = CustomBadLayerHandler()
QgsProject.instance().setBadLayerHandler(bad_layer_handler)

# Open the project
project = QgsProject.instance()
success = project.read(project_file)
```